# Finding and storing an address of a cell with value<=x

Tags: vba, find, range

I was wondering if someone would be kind enough to suggest some corrections to the indicated line in the script below.
It is throwing up "Object variable or With block variable not set" alarm.
I can only guess this means the "CellFound" range is not being set and that the problem lies within that line.
The "CellFound" variable is meant to find and store the location of a cell.value<=25 within DateRng for use by the following condition

To re-iterate, the entire script is to carry out the following tasks:

1. Locate a range that is located between 2 cells containing specific strings (DateRng)
2. Loop within this range for cells (i) that have a value <=25
3. Compare two other cells which are offset to "i"
4. Export a range of rows centered around "i" to different sheets pending the outcome of the above condition.

Thanks for your time.

```
Sub ReportCells()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim j, k As Long
Dim StartDate, FinishDate As String
Dim Sh As Worksheet: Set Sh = Sheets("Full chart and primary cals")
Dim CellFound As Range

'Range Extraction Script
'Search location and values
LookupColumn = "B"
StartDate = "2013.01.02 20:00"
FinishDate = "2013.01.09 20:00"
'Find Lower Limit
For j = 1 To 30000
    If Sh.Range(LookupColumn & j).Value = FinishDate Then FinishDateRow = j
    Next j
'Find Upper Limit
For k = FinishDateRow To 1 Step -1
    If Sh.Range(LookupColumn & k).Value = StartDate Then StartDateRow = k - 1
    Next k
'Set Range once located
Dim DateRng As Range: Set DateRng = Sh.Range(LookupColumn & StartDateRow & ":" & LookupColumn & FinishDateRow)
MsgBox DateRng.Address

'Find Cell
With DateRng
    LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
       ** Set CellFound = .Find(Sh.Range("M:M").Value <= 25, LookIn:=xlValues) **
        MsgBox CellFound.Address
        If Not CellFound Is Nothing And CellFound.Offset(0, -5).Value < CellFound.Offset(-1, -5).Value Then .Offset(-3, 0).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("DownT").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
        If Not CellFound Is Nothing And CellFound.Offset(0, -5).Value > CellFound.Offset(-1, -5).Value Then .Offset(-3, 0).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("UpT").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: The cell selection  and copy block has been modified to the code below. It seems that the value<=25 set range commands are not executing as they should be. They are definately filtering data but on what column I am not sure. The block is returning a range of cells of the correct size. But only one range (instead of around 20 or so). And of the wrong range of rows :S I guess any progress is progress regardless of if it's right or wrong

```
With Sheets("Full chart and primary cals")
    LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'For i = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    For i = 1 To LR
        With DateRng.Range("M" & i)
            If Range("M" & i).Value <= 25 Then Set CellFound = Sh.Range("M" & i)
            If Not CellFound Is Nothing Then .Offset(-5, 0).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("DownT").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
    End With
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Which line in particular's giving the error?

Comment: Sorry I though I marked it. Must have been looking at the screen too long today :S
Post edited: line marked as ****

Comment: Hi. V. sorry about that answer. Giant misunderstanding of the error. Please ignore the earlier 'solution' and revert to the original .Find() code which you had. I'll try to post a revised solution a bit later. Sorry abt that

Comment: No worries. I would have been nonethewiser either way :S
Original post has been edited to add some context to the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem........

```
'Loop through sheet looking for cells
    LR = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 10 To LR
        'Find cells in "M" and store thier reference in Cellref
        If .Range("M" & i).Value <= 25 Then Set Cellref = .Range("M" & i) Else Set Cellref = .Range("Z15")
        'Find if Cell ref is contained within DateRange and store result as bool
        If Not Application.Intersect(DateRange, Cellref) Is Nothing Then iSect = True Else iSect = False
        'Output cell ranges to the appropriate sheets
        If iSect = True And Cellref.Offset(0, -5) < Cellref.Offset(-10, -5) Then _
        Cellref.Offset(-3, 0).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("DownT").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
        If iSect = True And Cellref.Offset(0, -5) > Cellref.Offset(-10, -5) Then _
        Cellref.Offset(-3, 0).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("UpT").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your code you're misusing the `Range.Find()` function, which will most probably cause it to return `Nothing` instead of a meaningful range.

- `Sh.Range("M:M").Value` will throw a Type Mismatch error as you cannot use the `.Value` property of a `Range` containing multiple cells. As this error is contained within the arguments of your .Find function it's entirely possibly it's just being ignored but it will still cause `.Find` to return `Nothing`.
- Even were that not the case `Sh.Range("A1") <= 25` evaluates to either `True` or `False` (Depending on the value of A1) and the `Find` function would then search `DateRng` for the first instance of `True` or `False` within that range.

I'd recommend some [further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx) on how the `Range.Find` function works as it may not be suitable for the task you have in mind.

Comment: I had no idea that Find returned a true/false value. I was under the impression it would return a reference/range. Or is that what the Range. part of Range.find is for? Anyway, I solved the issue (and a number of them that followed after it over the weekend. The final solution is pasted below (without any .Find commands)

Comment: It's not that `Find` returns a true or false value, it's that `<=` is a comparison operator. Therefore `Range("<range>").Value <= 25` evaluates to true or false based on whether the Value of the specified range is less than or equal to 25. So `Find(Range("A1") <= 25,...)` would be the same as `Find(True, ...)` if the value of A1 was less than or equal to 25.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. Not only have you improved my rudimentary understanding of VB functions and syntax, but also why the solution I found actually worked.